# Terraform AWS MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam

I probably misunderstand something about IAM permissions. I need a Lambda function to generate STS tokens, and here is my terraform to do that:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudfront_logs_to_es_lambda_role" {
  name = "cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowlambdaToAssumeRole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MY-ACCOUNT-ID:role/cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

This code raises this error: **MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::MY-ACCOUNT-ID:role/cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test"**

I understand that I cannot put in the assume_role_policy a role that I am creating in the same time.

However, my question is: How can I attach this statement:

```
{
      "Sid": "AllowlambdaToAssumeRole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MY-ACCOUNT-ID:role/cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
```

to the role, after creating the role.

The only way I could make my code work is by first making a terraform apply of:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudfront_logs_to_es_lambda_role" {
  name = "cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-${local.env_type}"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }   
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

And then making:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudfront_logs_to_es_lambda_role" {
  name = "cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowlambdaToAssumeRole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MY-ACCOUNT-ID:role/cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Edit:

Here is the Python code that requires the  role can assume itself for STS token generation:

```
sts = boto3.client("sts")

creds = sts.assume_role(RoleArn=terraform_role_arn, RoleSessionName="lambdastsassume")
```

Comment: Instead of harcoding the arn in there let terraform resolve the dependecy by referencing aws_iam_role.cloudfront_logs_to_es_lambda_role.arn .

Comment: Then, it's a self-referential block. I am calling a role that I am creating in the same time ... :/

Comment: Sorry, meant to say `aws_iam_role.cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test.arn` - you do have two different roles involved in this, right?

Comment: Nope, it's a single role ... And I need this second statement, even though I don't really understand why. If I don't have it, I have an STS Authorization error in my lambda

Comment: You do not need it, you do not need and should not need to self-assume.

Comment: I need it so that the role can assume itself for STS token generation. Based on https://github.com/dbnegative/lambda-cloudfront-log-ingester

Comment: But again ... I don't reallly understand why

Comment: Create a pull request or fork the code and remove the self assume.

Comment: Here is the error I have when I do what you suggest: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::******:assumed-role/cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test/cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::****:role/cloudfront-logs-to-elasticsearch-test",

Comment: I added the Python code that throws this error when I don't have this permission